# WiFi (r8712u) is not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 and my wifi has stopped working. I have an Asus USB Wifi Adapter and it is able to detect the wifi signals. However, upon clicking on my home wifi I am unable to connect to it. I have had a look at this issue *[WiFi (r8712u) is only working after doing rmmod & modprobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742347/wifi-r8712u-is-only-working-after-doing-rmmod-modprobe)*  but had no success.

I am providing the below information and hoping the ubuntu community can help me here! Please let me know if you need any more information to solve the issue.

**lshw -class network**

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:19:d1:85:4b:d4
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=1.1-0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 memory:90300000-9031ffff memory:90324000-90324fff ioport:30c0(size=32)
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3.3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f4:6d:04:8b:44:b1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8712u multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bc2:3300 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1791 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. WL-167G v3 802.11n Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82P965/G965 Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G965 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:03.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 82P965/G965 HECI Controller (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HB/HR (ICH8/R) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) 4 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HR/HO/HH (ICH8R/DO/DH) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
02:00.0 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE6101/6102 single-port PATA133 interface (rev b1)
06:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: ESS Technology ES1938/ES1946/ES1969 Solo-1 Audiodrive (rev 02)
06:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB22A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [iOHCI-Lynx]
```

**rmmod r8712u && sudo modprobe r8712u** ( I have tried this as suggested in the above mentioned link but did not have any success. I have even tried restarting the network manager as mentioned in the link but had no success even there).

```
[ 1732.118252] usbcore: deregistering interface driver r8712u
[ 1732.436048] usb 1-3.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1732.652796] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[ 1732.653771] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[ 1732.653777] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[ 1732.654323] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[ 1733.065831] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0010
[ 1733.065839] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = f4:6d:04:8b:44:b1
[ 1733.065845] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[ 1733.069364] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8712u
[ 1733.101181] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1733.808456] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[ 1733.809196] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
[ 1733.916265] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1733.973323] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

***(An interesting piece of information here might be that when I turn the hotspot on on my phone, I am able to connect to my phone's wifi with the same setup. However, it is the home wifi I have been having problem connecting to. I have checked and rechecked the password I am entering and it is correct.)***

***Edit: Adding the wireless-info.txt contents here.***

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Jun 2016 00:34 IST +0530

Booted last: 10 Jun 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 26 May 2016 21:56 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-23-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 16 23:03:32 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection [8086:104b] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection [8086:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bc2:3300 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1791 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. WL-167G v3 802.11n Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

r8712u                159744  0
cfg80211              499712  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:90300000-90320000 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5894 errors:0 dropped:2201 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1879837 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:1148881 (1.1 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2451     1  0 Jun09 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Manufacturer Realtek 
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        ASUS WL-167G V3
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8712u
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         39 (Device disconnected by user or client)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-3/1-3.3/1-3.3:1.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    no
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0,2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   81d133ad-d1c3-4ebf-a108-7837c7e5e881 | Sid Mi Phone
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   4a6effa2-47de-4606-bdd6-13d9afcba61e | Sid

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        82566DC Gigabit Network Connection
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               1.1-0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID          BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Sid Mi Phone  <MAC 'Sid Mi Phone' [AN1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no        
Sid           <MAC 'Sid' [AC1]>  Infra  10    2457 MHz  54 Mbit/s  56      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Spark         <MAC 'Spark' [AN3]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  7       ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sid Mi Phone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sid Mi Phone | type=wifi | permissions=user:sid:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Sid Mi Phone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sid]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sid | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Sid
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Sid' [AC1]>
                    ESSID:"Sid"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                              48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac02000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Signal level=57/100  

##### module infos ######################

[r8712u]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8712/r8712u.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin
author:         Larry Finger
description:    rtl871x wireless lan driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     C6F0E0D1D849C2145DD5F72
depends:        
staging:        Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           wifi_test:int
parm:           video_mode:int
parm:           chip_version:int
parm:           rfintfs:int
parm:           lbkmode:int
parm:           hci:int
parm:           network_mode:int
parm:           channel:int
parm:           mp_mode:int
parm:           wmm_enable:int
parm:           vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           vcs_type:int
parm:           busy_thresh:int
parm:           ht_enable:int
parm:           cbw40_enable:int
parm:           ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rf_config:int
parm:           power_mgnt:int
parm:           low_power:int
parm:           ifname: Net interface name, wlan%d=default (string)
parm:           initmac:MAC-Address, default: use FUSE (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-23-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[r8712u]
ampdu_enable: 1
busy_thresh: 40
cbw40_enable: 1
channel: 1
chip_version: 2
hci: 1
ht_enable: 1
ifname: wlan%d
initmac: (null)
lbkmode: 0
low_power: 0
mp_mode: 0
network_mode: 0
power_mgnt: 0
rf_config: 1
rfintfs: 2
vcs_type: 1
video_mode: 1
vrtl_carrier_sense: 2
wifi_test: 0
wmm_enable: 0

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x104b (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (r8712u)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  252.098895] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  252.099852] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[  252.099859] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[  252.100405] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[  252.509037] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0010
[  252.509045] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[  252.509051] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[  252.621139] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  253.328535] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[  253.329400] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
[  253.436347] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 6 times)
[  354.796336] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  355.289572] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  355.766426] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 7 times)
[  604.735424] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 1020.413046] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 1447.413629] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[ 1447.414604] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[ 1447.414610] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[ 1447.415169] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[ 1447.865302] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0010
[ 1447.865310] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ 1447.865316] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[ 1448.079037] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1448.784428] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[ 1448.785170] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
[ 1448.892384] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[ 1732.652796] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[ 1732.653771] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[ 1732.653777] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[ 1732.654323] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[ 1733.065831] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0010
[ 1733.065839] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ 1733.065845] usb 1-3.3: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[ 1733.101181] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1733.808456] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[ 1733.809196] r8712u 1-3.3:1.0 wlan0: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
[ 1733.916265] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 4 times)
[ 2012.843797] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the setup I use for my 16.04 wifi setup and works flawlessly.

auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet static

address 10.1.1.2

netmask 255.0.0.0

broadcast 10.255.255.255

gateway 10.1.1.1

wpa-ssid network-name

wpa-psk pre-shared-key

Change parameters accordingly of course